# python email error

Tags: python

I am trying to email a results file. I am getting an import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "email_results.py", line 5, in ?  
    from email import encoders  
ImportError: cannot import name encoders
```

I am also unsure on how to get this to connect to the server. Can anyone help? Thanks

```
#!/home/build/test/Python-2.6.4
import smtplib
import zipfile
import tempfile
from email import encoders
from email.message import Message
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

def send_file_zipped(the_file, recipients, sender='myname@myname.com'):
 zf = tempfile.TemporaryFile(prefix='mail', suffix='.zip')
 zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zf, 'w')
 zip.write(the_file)
 zip.close()
 zf.seek(0)

 # Create the message
 themsg = MIMEMultipart()
 themsg['Subject'] = 'File %s' % the_file
 themsg['To'] = ', '.join(recipients)
 themsg['From'] = sender
 themsg.preamble = 'I am not using a MIME-aware mail reader.\n'
 msg = MIMEBase('application', 'zip')
 msg.set_payload(zf.read())
 encoders.encode_base64(msg)
 msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment',filename=the_file + '.zip')

 themsg.attach(msg)
 themsg = themsg.as_string()

 # send the message
 smtp = smtplib.SMTP()
 smtp.connect()
 smtp.sendmail(sender, recipients, themsg)
 smtp.close()
```

Comment: So how did you wind up solving the problem?  email is part of the standard library, so why didn't it work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem isn't that you can't connect to the server, it's that you aren't able to import email.encoders for some reason.  Do you have a file named email.py or email.pyc by any chance?

Comment: To fix this for python 2.x, only allow explicit relative imports: `from __future__ import aboslute_import`